# Need to combine csv files into one then import to csv into a table in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, linux, shell, csv

I am not sure I am going about this in the correct way but what I need to do is take folder full of .csv files and create one .csv file that I then will import into a talbe in mysql.  I have tried to break this down into sections so I can learn each part then hopefully put the whole package together.
I learn that in mysql now by default you are not allowed to upload a file into the database using the file import.  I was able to work through that and get a python script to upload the file I need into my mysql table catch is that I have to chown on the file to mysql so it will wortk.  Now I was hoping to add to the python script a way to combine the files and then run the upload in one script but have had trouble getting a script to combine the files so since I am using a linux server for this I found the cat command for the shell which works great.  In one simple command I can combine the directory with the .csv and place it in the directory where I need it.
Anyways what I have now is a shell script that looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

#sudo chown root /tmp/qvd.csv

sudo rm /tmp/qvd.csv
cat /media/backup/ups/QVD/*.csv > /media/backup/ups/qvd.csv
#cat /media/backup/ups/QVD/*.csv > /media/backup/ups/qvdbackup
#rm /media/backup/ups/QVD/*.csv
sudo chown mysql /tmp/qvd.csv
cat /media/backup/ups/qvd.csv > /tmp/qvd.csv
rm /media/backup/ups/qvd.csv
python /media/backup/ups/ups.py
```

If this script would work I would not have problems but I need to automatically delete or be able to overwrite the /tmp/qvd.csv file.  Otherwise it works great.  Combines, moves the files that are being combined to a archive folder.  Moves the created qvd.csv file to the /tmp folder and then calls the python script to upload the file.

I am new at linux but all the time I find things that are so much easier than windows.  I want to learn more.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Combine all CSVs to a single one: `cat /media/backup/ups/QVD/*.csv > /tmp/qvd.csv`
2. Import (however you'd do that)

Comment: I already understand part one of your reply is you look at my script I am able to combine with no problem.  My problem is the permissions that the combined file has to have to be uploaded to mysql.  I have to manually chown the qvd.csv file so my python can upload it.  I I do not delete the qvd.csv file it will not let me overwrite it because of the owner.  So in my script unless there is a easier way I have to create the qvd.csv then chown to mysql and upload it and then I need to be able to delete it for the next time the script runs.

Comment: >ou need to understand how permissions work. Give the user running the script full access to the file, then it can be overwritten.

Read up on how permissions work.

Comment: I adjusted the permission as suggested and it worked fine.  Thanka